# sorting results from 2 tables with pagination (php, mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, pagination

I would like to create buttons that change sorting of database output.
Im quering one table and output results with some pagination class. I can easily ORDER results by columns ascending or descending.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name, address FROM restaurant WHERE accepted = '1' ORDER BY id DESC";
$pagination = new Pagination();
$pagination->page = $_GET['page'];
$pagination->perPage = 10;
$pagination->classNormal = 'someClass';
$pagination->classSelected = 'someClass2';
$pagination->sql($sql);
```

Then in while loop I have those results and another mysql auery.

```
while($row = $pagination->getRows()) {
$sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT prod_name) AS nr_of_prod FROM menu WHERE id = '".$row['id']."'" ;                
$do1->doQuery($sql2);
$row_amount = $do1->getRows();
//... and here is some data output
```

Now, the question is how can I sort/order all the paging result by column from this second query (for exampple by nr_of_prod)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the second query right in the first:

```
SELECT id, name, address,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT prod_name) nr_of_prod
        FROM menu
        WHERE menu.id = restaurant.id
       ) nr_of_prod
FROM restaurant
WHERE accepted = '1'
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Also, why are you using some pagination class instead of using MySQL `LIMIT`?

You can also write it like this (profile both and pick, the best one depends on the relative size of the tables):

```
SELECT id, name, address, nr_of_prod
FROM restaurant JOIN
     (SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT prod_name) nr_of_prod
      FROM menu
      GROUP BY id
     ) nr_of_prod USING (id)
WHERE accepted = '1'
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Thank you! Its working like a charm :) Can I use this solution for more tables? I mean Can I use as many "select" in one query as I need?

Comment: @gordonek Yup. Not everything "fits" there, but sure, anything that returns a single value (i.e. not a list of values) will work there.

Answer (score -2):

I picked up this pagination code from another website and it runs great on my pages... 
NOT: This is not my code and I do not claim it as such.

```
    /*
    Place code to connect to your DB here.
*/
include('config.php');  // include your code to connect to DB.

$tbl_name="";       //your table name
// How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
$adjacents = 3;

/* 
   First get total number of rows in data table. 
   If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
*/
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages[num];

/* Setup vars for query. */
$targetpage = "filename.php";   //your file name  (the name of this file)
$limit = 30;                                //how many items to show per page
$page = $_GET['page'];
if($page) 
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
else
    $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

/* Get data. */
$sql = "SELECT column_name FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

/* Setup page vars for display. */
if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
$prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
$next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
$lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

/* 
    Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
    We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
*/
$pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1)
{   
    $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
    //previous button
    if ($page > 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\"><<- PREVIOUS</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\"><<- PREVIOUS</span>";   

    //pages 
    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
    {   
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page)
                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
        }
    }
    elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
    {
        //close to beginning; only hide later pages
        if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
        {
            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
        }
        //in middle; hide some front and some back
        elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
        }
        //close to end; only hide early pages
        else
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
    }

    //next button
    if ($page < $counter - 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">NEXT ->></a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">NEXT ->></span>";
    $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
}



    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

    // Your while loop here

    }
?>
```